# How to modify the content of a text file in C

Tags: c

My text file has data like -
(item) (no of item)

```
mobile 5
book 6
pen 2
laptop 7
```

I want to modify no of pen in the text file.

E.g: I want to decrease count value of pen by 1.
So, my text file should be like this after the operation:

```
mobile 5
book 6
pen 1
laptop 7
```

I was trying with fscanf and fprintf function but it did not work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h> // For exit() function
int main()
{
    int i;
    char c[1000];
    char *str="mobile";
    FILE *fptr;

    if ((fptr = fopen("out.txt", "r+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);         
    }

    // reads text until newline 
    char buf[100];
    int item;
    char* temp[10];
    /*
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    fscanf(stdin, "%s %d",buf, &item);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s %d\n",buf, item);
    }
    */
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    fscanf(fptr,"%s %d", buf , &item);
    if(strstr(buf,str))
    {
     fprintf(fptr,"%s %d",buf ,item+1);
     }
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me with this one.

Comment: You cannot write to the same file you are reading from.

Comment: I am too lazy to write the code for you but here is my suggestion read the file and record the key and value after that manipulate the result and then write the manipulated onto the same or different file (open it again) or you can seek the writer back to the top to rewrite everything. Sound like a homework btw

Comment: see [fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)

Comment: You have to spool the text file. You canot just replace the value with fseek because if the value was "10" and it becomes "9" you have 1 character less.

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fptr_read;
FILE *fptr_write;
int offset = 0;

    if ((fptr_read = fopen("out.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Can't open file for reading");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);         
    }

    if ((fptr_write = fopen("out.txt", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Can't open file for writing");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);         
    }
```

when ever you choose to write to the file you must move the pointer in the file to the specific file location

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{

fscanf(fptr,"%s %d", buf , &item);

if(strstr(buf,str))
{  
current_pos = ftell(fptr_read)   //gets position of file pointer for the read
fseek(fptr_write, current_pos, SEEK_SET)   //sets file pointer of write to read (basically overwrite at that position)
fprintf(fptr_write,"%s %d",buf ,item-1); //subtract one not add one
}

}
```

Comment: this program will subtract 1 from mobile since that is hard-coded in rather than pen

Answer (score 0):

Complete code is left for you to do, (including error checking) but here is one set of steps that could be used. (There are many alternatives.) Most steps here are provided with small code snippet hints:

1) typedef a struct to match known contents of file.  (if file contents change at some point, struct definitions might need to change):

```
typedef struct {
   char item[20];//change size as needed
   int qty;
}RECORD;
```

2) Open file for read, count lines in file.  Something like:

```
...
int lineCnt = 0;
do 
{
    ch = fgetc(fptr_read);
    if(ch == '\n')
        lineCnt++;
} while (ch != EOF);
...
```

3) use lineCnt to create instances of `RECORD`:

```
RECORD *record = calloc(lineCnt, sizeof(*records));
```

4) Open file for read, read file line by line using *[fgets(...)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)*.  Parse each line using *[strtok(...)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)* to get items in record into struct members:

```
char line[80];
char *tok;
int count = 0;
while(fgets(line, 80, fptr_read)
{
    tok = strtok(line, " ");
    if(tok)
    {
        strcpy(record[count].item, tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if(tok)
        {
            record[count].qty = atoi(tok);
        }
    }
}
```

5) Modify member values as needed using normal assignment statements for integers and/or strings.  (or using *[fscanf(...)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm)* as you have tried. [it does work.].)

6) Synthesize new strings from modified records using, for example *[sprintf(...)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)*, Open the file for write, and use *[fputs(...)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fputs.htm)* to write modified content into file:

```
...
for(i=0;i<lineCnt;i++)
{
   sprintf(line[i], "%s  %d\n", record[i].item, record[i].qty);
   fputs(line, fptr_write); 
}
...
```

7) Finally, don't forget to free any allocated memory, and close any opened files.  Your file content is now modified and readable.